# mod_rewrite old Domain Rules to new Domain

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I am trying to forward some old Dynamic Links to a new Target

The old Link had RewriteRule in use

```
http://www.olddomain.com/index.php?cms=blog&action=..
```

So I will forward `cms=blog` to a new Domain `http://www.newdomain.com/blog`

Comment: You know what the BIG Problem is Mr. -1. Not everything is easy to explain to Google. And People who you can explain will not listen to you! Thanks for your -1

Comment: This: `RewriteRule   ^/docs/(.+)  http://new.example.com/docs/$1  [R,L]` does not work. It should be something like: `RewriteRule   ^docs/(.+)  http://new.example.com/docs/$1  [R,L]`. But it is not clear what you want, take some time to include some complete URL examples in your question if you want someone to fully understand what you need. Rules are not enough, specially when they are the reason for the question.

Comment: Hey faa, Thanks again for your reply.. I was editing my Question to explain better. I was trying this way but did not solve it. `RedirectMatch ^/?cms=blog(.*) http://www.newdomain.com/blog/ [R=301,L]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match querystrings you could use `RewriteCond` directive. The complete rule that you need to place inside www.olddomain.com/.htaccess would be:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)cms=blog(&|$)
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.newdomain.com/blog? [R=302,L]
```

Change 302 to 301 if necessary.

Comment: Hey Salman thanks. The forward is working but the URL looks like this now `http://www.newdomain.com/blog/?p=shop&action=...` It should only forward to `http://www.newdomain.com/blog` without to take the condiditions before.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Note the `?` at the end of URL, it is required.

Comment: You are the King of the day ;)